# Windows 10 compatibility problem for Heroes of Might and Magic IV

Tags: technical-issues, windows-10, heroes-of-might-and-magic-4

I've been a big fan of the older Heroes of Might and Magic games or more specifically, the fourth one. However, ever since I've updated to Windows 10, I have failed to get the game to run and my previous compatibility solution no longer works.

At the moment, it allows me to fully install it (from a copy I've been using for years) and will open a launcher window but, if I hit play from there or try to run the actual game some other way, it will simply close the launcher andnot do anything.

**What I've tried:**

- Setting compatibility mode to every option below Windows 10.
- Running as administrator
- Uninstalling and reinstalling
- Installing and trying to run on two different computers (both Windows 10)

The first two list items allowed me to easily get it running on Windows 8 but have not been cutting it for Windows 10.

So I was wondering, is there a way to get HOMM4 running on my Windows 10 computer?

Comment: If you're trying to play a disc based version of the game then the problem is likely that the Windows 10 doesn't support the copy protection it used. You'd need to use a No CD crack or buy the DRM-free GOG.com version.